# Can Shared Prefrences applied on Sqlite Database login register system?

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

I have made login and register system for app using sq-lite database .Now my question is can on sq lite database login/register system ,shared preferences can applied on them to save key values.????

Comment: Your question is not very clear

Comment: in login register system using xamp,we apply shared prefrences to save user key values over the internet. i want to ask that can we do this using sqlite database login register system  without using internet

Comment: Yes, you can use sqlite for Registration & Login system, but in your app other feature should also support's for offline mode, Also it will be only on that device.

Comment: thats fine,but can i save key values of login to prevent user not loging again and again using app ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. you can store value. if user `login` set value to 1
and next time check again if value is 1. Open `MainActivity`.
when user `logout`, set value to 0.
but recommend is to use `sharedpreference`. Where you can save data under **certain key**.

Comment: Yes. you can use.